# How can i prevent adding certain amount of characters with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to be able to allow the following string

```
12,3232,1-4,5-90,323
```

What i'm trying to avoid is :

1. Adding more then 1 comma between digits

   12,,,3232,1---4,5------90,,,,,323

2 .Prevent first number to be negative

```
-1,2,3
```

3 .Prevent invalid chars as first letter

```
?1,2,3
```

Thanks to @anubhava i can prevent add more then one dash between digits

```
^(?:(?:\d+-)?\d+(?:,(?:\d+-)?\d+)*|\d+)(?:,(?:(?:\d+-)?\d+(?:,(?:\d+-)?\d+)*]|\d+))*$ // 12,3232,1-4,5-90
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this regex for validation:

```sh
/^(?:\[(?:\d+-)?\d+(?:,(?:\d+-)?\d+)*]|(?:\d+-)?\d+)(?:,(?:\[(?:\d+-)?\d+(?:,(?:\d+-)?\d+)*]|(?:\d+-)?\d+))*$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oLAAcw/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group #1

  - `\[`: Match `[`
  - `(?:\d+-)?`: Match digits followed by `-` in an optional non-capture group
  - `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group #2

    - `,`: Match a comma
    - `(?:\d+-)?`: Match digits followed by `-` in an optional non-capture group
    - `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
  - `)*`: End Start non-capture group #2. Match 0 or more of this group
  - `]`: Match closing `]`
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?:\d+-)?\d+`: Match digits-digits or digits
- `)`: Match closing non-capture group #1

Comment: for some reason it's not restrict text...i'm checking

Comment: This fails for `12,3232,[1-4,5-90],[4,2-5],323,6-7`. @RoyBarOn noted this should pass in the comments.

Comment: @anubhava i'll use you suggestion since it's working - i'll update the post if i'll need more help - thanks!

Comment: Looks great! +1!

Comment: @anubhava i've updated the question - can you please help?

Comment: @RoyBarOn: Invalid cases are already [not being matched by my suggested regex](https://regex101.com/r/vz2Axr/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

`(\\d+[,-])*+\\d+`

You have a number `\\d+` followed by a "," or "-" `[,-]` witch is repeated multible times `*+` and ends with another number.